# Backbone - Block url access from editing in browser

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js

I would like to block an url from directly accessing it from editing it in browser.

Example: 
I want to force user to use the active button to access this URL.

http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/#/active

But actualy he can just type it in the browser url bar.

Thanks

Comment: Note: any time you start with "i want to force the user", you're almost certainly asking the wrong question. Browsers make a point of not letting designers be so obnoxious to users.

Comment: I didnt really meant it, but i just want that the only way to go through this url is to click the button.

Comment: Why do you want a url that shouldn't work as a url? It's javascript, just update the content, and have the router do nothing there.

Comment: Also you can update the url with javascript, and then ignore that url if it is accessed directly. That sounds like what you asked, though I am not sure why you even need to update the url in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag for source ( in your case - isFromButton = true ) and in the  function of route you can check the flag  , see below

```
  routes: {
        "active":                 "activeFunction",    // #active
      },

      activeFunction: function() {
        if (isFromButton === true ) {

        }else {
            return;
        }
      },
```